# When is a matrix congruent to a diagonal matrix and how to find the congruent transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What matrix can be congruent to a diagonal matrix and how can we find the congruent transform and the diagonal matrix?

One special case is when the congruence is also similarity.

For example, for a normal matrix, we can use a transform which is both similar and congruent to convert it into a diagonal matrix. But is it the only case where congruence to a diagonal matrix is of interest?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2):

As you might know, if a matrix $A$ is real symmetric, then it is always diagonalisable. In fact, it is *orthogonally* diagonalisable. So we can find an orthogonal matrix $P$ such that $P^TAP=D$ is a diagonal matrix having entries equal to the eigenvalues of $A$. This is nothing but the consequence of the Spectral decomposition theorem. As you rightly said, we can also say in this case that $A$ is *congruent* to $D$ (even $A$ is similar to $D$). In other words, by performing appropriate row operations and the same column operations on $A$, we can diagonalise $A$ to the matrix $D$.

However, we can diagonalise $A$ (if it is diagonalisable) even without the Spectral decomposition, provided $A$ is symmetric. We do this by performing congruent operations on $A$.

An important result on congruence operations is

> **Theorem.** An $n\times n$ real symmetric matrix $A$ of rank $r$ is congruent to an $n\times n$ real diagonal matrix $D$ with non-zero elements in the first $r$ diagonal positions and zero elsewhere.

This result can be extended by stating:

> An $n\times n$ real symmetric matrix $A$ of rank $r$ is congruent to the $n\times n$ real diagonal matrix $G$ whose first $m$ diagonal elements are $1$, the next $r-m$ diagonal elements are $-1$ and the remaining diagonal elements, if any, are all zero.

(I had asked a similar question regarding the proof of the result [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2235085/proving-every-real-symmetric-matrix-is-congruent-to-the-canonical-form-mathrm).)

Thus $G$ takes the form $$\begin{pmatrix} I_m &  O &  O \\ O & -I_{r-m} &  O \\ O &  O &  O \\\end{pmatrix}\,,$$

which is said to be the *normal form of $A$ under congruence*.

Finally, we can say with relative ease that

> **Theorem.** Two real symmetric matrices of the same order are congruent iff they have the same rank and same [signature](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixSignature.html).

---

**An example:**

Suppose we have to diagonalise the matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 4 & 3 \\4 & 6 & 3 \\3 & 3 &1 \\\end{pmatrix}.$$

Or equivalently, diagonalise the quadratic form $$Q(x,y,z)=2x^2+6y^2+z^2+8xy+6xz+6yz\,.$$

Indeed, we can find the eigenvalues of $A$ and the corresponding normalised eigenvectors to perform the eigendecomposition. But we don't need an orthogonal transformation for the diagonalisation; any nonsingular transformation would suffice. (We don't even need to convert $A$ to the normal form).

We rewrite $A$ as $I_3AI_3=A \tag{$\star$}$

We apply the operations $R_2'=R_2-2R_1,R_3'=R_3-\frac{3}{2}R_1$ in the first step, followed by the same column operations in the next step. Then we perform $R_3'=R_3-\frac{3}{2}R_2$ and its corresponding column operation to reduce $A$ to the matrix $D=\mathrm{diag}(2,-2,1)$.

We find that $(\star)$ has become $$P^TAP=D\,,$$ where $P=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -2 & 3/2 \\0 & 1 & -3/2 \\0 & 0 &1 \\\end{pmatrix}$ is a nonsingular matrix.

Equivalently, the quadratic form $Q(x,y,z)$ has been transformed to some $$Q(u,v,w)=2u^2-2v^2+w^2$$ by means of the transformation $(x,y,z)^T=P(u,v,w)^T$.

Then the transformation matrix is given by $P^{-1}$ and the nonsingular transformation (congruent transformation) that diagonalises the given quadratic form is $(u,v,w)^T=P^{-1}(x,y,z)^T$.

This procedure is especially helpful for $3\times 3$ matrices, instead of finding the eigenvalues/eigenvectors or applying Lagrange's method of diagonalisation of a quadratic form.