# Finding a matrix $P$ such that $B=P^TAP$ given $A,B$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have 2 matrices, $A,B$ associated with the same bilinear application, where $A$ is expressed using the canonical basis $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$. I need to find the basis $B$ is associated with so I can compute $P$.

$$B=P^TAP$$

I would love a method that doesn't involve solving a big system of equations.

$$
A= \begin{bmatrix}
3 & -2 & 0 \\
5 & 7 & -8 \\
0 & -4 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$
B=
\begin{bmatrix}
25 & 6 & -8 \\
17 & 0 & -9 \\
-4 & -5 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Can you tell about your method and progress for the question?

Comment: Making P a matrix with all its integers variables a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i and then making matrix multiplication, then solving the system

Comment: If $A,B$ were symmetric, then you could [orthogonally diagonalize](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/380191/73324) each of them, getting $A=P^TCP$ and $B=Q^TDQ$.  Assuming $C=D$ (else there is no solution), then $B=Q^TPAP^TQ=(P^{-1}Q)^TA(P^{-1}Q)$.

Comment: Does a method for non-symmetric matrices exist?

Comment: How are these matrices “associated with a bilinear application?” If the bilinear form is something like $x^TAx$, then only the symmetric part of $A$ contributes to it, so there’s no a priori reason to believe that there is a solution in the first place. What makes you think that one is possible?

Comment: It's possible because I'm making the inverse problem from a easier one in which the 2 basis and the bilineal application were given,so it was trivial to solve por P and B. However, our teacher told us to do the inverse one

Comment: PD: the bilinear application is the form f(x, y) =Xt A Y